# Trigger to compare a count value from one table with a value from second table

Tags: oracle, plsql, count, database-trigger, multiple-tables

I am a beginner in sql and am trying to create a trigger that compares two values from two different tables with the same values from a column TrainingCde_ID

Table 1 - Participants

```
 Participant_ID | TrainingCde_ID 
 22             | SPOT2          
 23             | SPOT2     
 24             | SPOT2  
 11             | PRT1
```

Table 2 - Training

```
 TrainingCde_ID | Capacity 
 SPOT2           | 2          
 TOP5            | 50         
 PRT1            | 20
```

I wanted to include a count statement, that counts how many participants want to attend the training and then compare if the value is greater than the Capacity value in the second table, there would be an error raise.

The code should practically tell me that if more than 2 participants wants to attend the training e.g. SPOT2, then there would be error, telling me, that the capacity is full.

```
create or replace trigger trg_ucast
before insert or update 
on participants
for each row 
declare
    c_capacity training.capacity%type;
    Part_ID  integer;
begin

    select capacity into c_capacity
    from training
    where trainingCde_ID = :new.trainingCde_ID;

    select count (participant_ID) as PID into Part_ID
    from Participants ;

    if :new.Part_ID > :new.c_capacity then 
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'FULL CAPACITY!');
    end if;
end;
/
```

This is what i created then there is this error >>

```
ERROR: pls-00049: bad bind variable 'new.Part_ID'
ERROR: pls-00049: bad bind variable 'new.c_capacity'
```

Can somebody help me with the error? Or if theres a mistake in my code?

Comment: I've improved your code formatting: `begin` should line up with the corresponding `declare` and `end`, code within `if`/`end if` should be indented, etc.

Comment: And what if two (or more) people are trying to enroll at the same time?  The uncommitted activity of one will be invisible to the other.  So if their is only room for one more enrolled, both will think there is room for them, but when both commit, the course will be over-enrolled.

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
if :new.Part_ID > :new.c_capacity then 
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'FULL CAPACITY!');
end if;
```

should not use `:new` i.e. should be:

```
if Part_ID > c_capacity then 
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'FULL CAPACITY!');
end if;
```

However you will still have an issue because your row-level trigger selects from the table it fires on, which is problematic.